# Python : csv unexpected quotes in last element

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, csv

I'm using Python 2.7.6 and learning to use the `csv` module. My script somehow added unexpected double quotes and several spaces after my last element, when I parsed input file to the CSV output file on my last element in each line. I could not remove those double quotes using regular substitution.

The only way that I could remove the extra double quote is to use:
  `tmp[1] = tmp[1][:-3]`

I don't understand how the extra double quote is added when I parsed my input. Please let me know why or how those double quote were added to the `partno` when the input file did not have them.

**My code**:

```
import re
import csv

fname = "inputfile"
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print 'File cannot be opened:', fname
    exit()

domain = []
server = []
model =  []
serial = []
dn = []
memsize = []
vid = []
partno = []
csv_out = open('/tmp/out.csv','wb')
writer = csv.writer(csv_out)

for line in fhand:
    words = line.split("; ")
    tmp_row_list = []
    for number in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]:
        tmp=words[number].split("=")
        if "}" in tmp[1]:
            tmp[1] = tmp[1][:-3]
            #tmp[1] = re.sub('}','', tmp[1])
        if number == 0: domain.append(tmp[1])
        if number == 1: server.append(tmp[1])
        if number == 2: model.append(tmp[1])
        if number == 3: serial.append(tmp[1])
        if number == 4: dn.append(tmp[1])
        if number == 5: memsize.append(tmp[1])
        if number == 6: vid.append(tmp[1])
        if number == 7: partno.append(tmp[1])
    rows = zip(domain,server,model,serial,dn,memsize,vid,partno)
    writer.writerows(rows)
csv_out.close()
```

**Input file**:

```
ffile:@{Ucs=uname; ServerId=4/6; Model=UCSB-B200-M3; Serial=FCH; AssignedToDn=; TotalMemory=98304; Vid=V06; PartNumber=73-14689-04}
ffile:@{Ucs=uname; ServerId=4/7; Model=UCSB-B200-M3; Serial=FCH; AssignedToDn=; TotalMemory=98304; Vid=V06; PartNumber=73-14689-04}
```

My **bad** output that has the strange double quotes before I had to remove them (if unrem the line with the re.sub, bad output with double quotes and extra spaces will show up in the last field/element):

```
uname,4/6,UCSB-B200-M3,FCH,,98304,V06,"73-14689-04
"
uname,4/7,UCSB-B200-M3,FCH,,98304,V06,"73-14689-04
"
```

Comment: You have a working code; the `for line in fhand` yields lines including the newline at the end; to remove them use `.rstrip('\n')` for example, or `re.sub('}|\n', ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can simplify that lot.

Given `input.txt` as:

```
ffile:@{Ucs=uname; ServerId=4/6; Model=UCSB-B200-M3; Serial=FCH; AssignedToDn=; TotalMemory=98304; Vid=V06; PartNumber=73-14689-04}
ffile:@{Ucs=uname; ServerId=4/7; Model=UCSB-B200-M3; Serial=FCH; AssignedToDn=; TotalMemory=98304; Vid=V06; PartNumber=73-14689-04}
```

Then using the following:

```
import re, csv

get_col_vals = re.compile('(?:\w+)=(.*?)[;}]').findall
with open('input.txt') as fin, open('output.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    csvout = csv.writer(fout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    csvout.writerows(get_col_vals(row) for row in fin)
```

The resulting `output.csv` is:

```
uname,4/6,UCSB-B200-M3,FCH,,98304,V06,73-14689-04
uname,4/7,UCSB-B200-M3,FCH,,98304,V06,73-14689-04
```